# 200 000 вопросов в базе русскоязычного сообщества!

Tags: обсуждение, вехи

Поздравляю, коллеги!

## 200 000 вопросов в базе знаний сообщества!

[image: 200 000 вопросов]

Вместе мы сделали еще один шаг для того, чтобы любой человек, знающий русский язык, мог стать лучше в программировании и имел равные возможности в доступе к информации безотносительно возраста, достатка и других несущественных различий.

Хотелось бы выразить огромную благодарность всем, кто был активен, всем, кто не боялся делать шаги навстречу знаниям и задавать вопросы, всем тем, кто делился своими знаниями с сообществом, всем, кто вносил улучшающие правки. Ребята, без вас ничего бы не получилось! Спасибо!

Comment: для сравнения на Киберфоруме только о C++ ~300000 "тем". Качество не знаю. Относительные доли трафика сдвинулись в какую-нибудь сторону за время существования ru.SO?

Comment: @jfs: Ну так киберфоруму бесконечное число лет.

Comment: сегодня как раз обратил внимание _" Задать вопрос и принять ответ -- 21.3k награждений "_, только 10% от всех вопросов имеют принятые ответы?

Comment: @teran так баджик же только 1 раз выдается юзеру. То есть 10% вопросов являются вопросами с первыми принятыми пользователями ответами.

Comment: @yolosora хах, действительно. че-то туплю :)

Comment: @jfs У меня нет данных по Киберфоруму, [кроме их странички для рекламодателей](http://www.cyberforum.ru/advert.php), которую они вряд ли часто обновляют. Заявлено, что у них в месяц где–то 3.2М посетителей и 11М просмотров. На Stack Overflow на русском мы имеем чуть меньше 1М посетителей и 3.5 просмотренных страниц в месяц (не знаю как Киберформу, но нас Яндекс отказывается индексировать до сих пор).

Comment: Греет мысль, что наша база знаний имеет крайне большую значимость для русскоязычной аудитории, раз на 200 000 вопросов на сайт приходит почти треть всего Киберфорума!

Comment: Насчёт возраста: всё же [не все равны тут](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61770/339911).

Comment: я имел в виду публичные данные типа: https://www.quantcast.com/ru.stackoverflow.com#trafficCard (для киберфорума не пытался искать)

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, часто задаю запросы на русском в Яндексе. В топе оказывается ru.SO (и qaru, куда уж без него). Видимо все-таки индексирует.